# Can not display deployed cloud function in firebase console

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I have try to deploy cloud function to firebase but i am confused
between command prompt and firebase console->project->functions.
Because in command prompt display deployed successfully but in
function tab there is no any functions.

I have follow below steps for deploy process

1. Download a sample function and place to c drive with folder name AddMessage.
2. Start command prompt and run "npm install -g firebase-tools"command.
3. After that i have run "firebase login" command and result is you have already logged in with email.
4. After that i have run "firebase init functions" command and give me project list and i have select a project with enter.And answer to some question that is in image.

   [image]
   5.After that i have run "firebase deploy --only functions" command.and give me below result.[image]

After that i have visit to https://console.firebase.google.com/ in check in selected project -> function but i got below screen.
[image]

Comment: I have also refer site for step : http://myhexaville.com/2017/03/22/firebase-cloud-functions/

Comment: Your console output makes it look like you didn't actually deploy any functions.  I would expect to see them individually named when you run the deploy command.

Comment: i get cleanupUserData function from https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/user-data-cleanup but i do not use node.js sdk is it possible?

Comment: Can you show me index.js?

Answer (score 4):

Firebase only deploys functions that are exported, 
so you have to make sure that the function you want to deploy is exported in your `index.js` file:

```
exports.yourFunction = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
// Your enter code here
}
```